# Iteration using pandas dataframe values

Tags: python, pandas, csv, iteration

While turning around the iteration, if the conditions are satisfied then the value is changed.
However, the original dataframe remains unchanged.
Is there a way to solve this?

(I know itertuples, iterrows loc can available. But I want to use values. (more faster))

```
import panda as pd
df = pd.read_csv(filename)
for value in df.values:
  if A:
    value[2] = 3
  print(value) # changed
df.to_csv(newfilename) # unchanged
```

Comment: Looping through values is not fast. Use vectorial code. Your code doesn't work because you modify the copy.

Comment: Performance is irrelevant if it doesn't work.  If you're just looking to change some fields, why would you get the very large and slow-to-load pandas module involved at all?  Just do it line by line.

Comment: No, using values is fater than itertuples, iterrows, loc. I just solved using iat, count idx then use df.iat[count, 2] = 3 instead of value[2] = 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I soled using iat.

```
import panda as pd
df = pd.read_csv(filename)
cnt = 0
for value in df.values:
  if A:
    #value[2] = 3
    df[cnt, 2] = 3
  print(value) # changed
  cnt += 1
df.to_csv(newfilename) # changed
```

Additionally, iteration (sec) : df.values < itertuples < iterrows

Answer (score 0):

The CSV should also be changed. I just tested this and it changed:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'A': [0,1,0,0,1,1,0,1,0],
    'B': [1,0,1,1,0,0,1,0,1],
})

for value in df.values:
    if value[0]==0:
        value[1]=5
        print(value) # changed
df #also changed
df.to_excel("output.xlsx") #also changed
```

Comment: thx for ur answer. I just solved using iat, count idx then use df.iat[count, 2] = 3 instead of value[2] = 3

Answer (score 0):

As mozway suggested, try vectorized code. This is generally a good thing when you work with pandas.

```
df.loc[CONDITION, COLUMN_NAME_TO_WRITE_TO] = NEW_VALUE
```

for your example, maybe something like

```
import panda as pd
df = pd.read_csv(filename)
df.loc[A, df.columns[2]] = 3      # instead of df.columns[INDEX] you could directly use the column name
df.to_csv(newfilename)
```

Comment: thx for ur answer. I just solved using iat, count idx then use df.iat[count, 2] = 3 instead of value[2] = 3